# RxJava - Retrofit dont making request with Rx

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, retrofit

I'm studying about `RxJava` with `Retrofit`, and I'm trying to combine two requests. But its not making a request to `getToken` api. It's a simple code just for study case

This is what I have now, what am I doing wrong?

```
 apiManager.getToken(body)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map { people -> saveUser(people) }
            .doOnNext { car -> Log.d("car",car.toString()) }
            .flatMap { car -> Observable.from(car!!.items) }
            .flatMap { carId -> val header = HashMap<String, String>()
                header.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + user!!.authorization)
                apiManager.getCarItens(header, carId.id!!)  }
            .doOnCompleted { showUser(user) }
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

Comment: braces. Just replace `map {}` with `map({})` ans so on, it should fix the problem

Comment: @Lamorak how to handle when I want to get a `List` of itens from `User`   by his `Id` ? `Observable.from(user.itens)` make it impossible cause I dont have the list yet

Comment: @Lamorak: the braces are ok, this is Kotlin :)

Comment: Actually I had a problem with wrong braces in kotlin. Somebody even wrote a [full post](https://android.jlelse.eu/kotlin-and-rx2-how-i-wasted-5-hours-because-of-wrong-brackets-581021717774) about it :)

Answer (score 1):

You are just defining your `Observable`, but you are not subscribing to it, so the stream won't get data at all:

```
apiManager.getToken(body)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .map { people -> saveUser(people) }
    .doOnNext { car -> Log.d("car", car.toString()) }
    .flatMap { car -> Observable.from(car!!.items) }
    .flatMap { carId ->
        val header = HashMap<String, String>()
        header.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + user!!.authorization)
        apiManager.getCarItens(header, carId.id!!)
    }
    .doOnCompleted { showUser(user) }
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe() // This is what you were missing!
```

I'd recommend you cleanup some things, though:

1. Avoid using `!!`: it will cause an `Exception` if the objects are null, which will bubble up, given that you are not handling them (you could, as an [`onError` parameter to `subscribe`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html)
2. Instead of `doOnCompleted`, use `onCompleted` parameter to `subscribe`, which makes it be next to the error handling, and it's easier to read